# Python: automatically call a parent function after child instantiation

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, python-object

Python 2.7

I would like to automotically call a function of a parent object after I instantiate its child

```
class Mother:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def call_me_maybe(self):
        print 'hello son'


class Child(Mother):

    def __init__(self):
        print 'hi mom'


# desired behavior

>>> billy = Child()
hi mom
hello son
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Edit, from a comment below:

"i should have made it more clearer in my question, what i really want is some sort of 'automatic' calling of the parent method triggered solely by the instantiation of the child, with no explicit calling of the parent method from the child. I was hoping there would be some sort of magic method for this but i dont think there is."

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`super`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods) but you should set your *superclass* to inherit from `object`:

```
class Mother(object):
#              ^
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def call_me_maybe(self):
        print 'hello son'


class Child(Mother):

    def __init__(self):
        print 'hi mom'
        super(Child, self).call_me_maybe()
```

---

```
>>> billy = Child()
hi mom
hello son
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `super()`?

```
class Child(Mother):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'hi mom'
        super(Child, self).call_me_maybe()
```

Comment: Since OP seems to use Python 2 he can't use the convenient `super()`. The 2.x version would be `super(Child, self).call_me_maybe()`.

Comment: @HannesOvrén: how do you know the OP is using Python 2?

Comment: @cdarke from their `print` statement

Comment: What @cdarke said :)   Also, his point about `Mother` inheriting from `object` is important too.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye:  I missed that.  I looked through the OP's history and found a python 3 question.

Comment: i should have made it more clearer in my question, what i really want is some sort of 'automatic' calling of the parent method triggered solely by the instantiation of the child, with no explicit calling of the parent method from the child. I was hoping there would be some sort of magic method for this but i dont think there is.

Answer (score 1):

Since the child class inherits the parents methods, you can simply call the method in the `__init__()` statement.

```
class Mother(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def call_me_maybe(self):
        print('hello son')


class Child(Mother):

    def __init__(self):
        print('hi mom')
        self.call_me_maybe()
```

Comment: Although this does the same thing, OP's request is that you call the parent method. Using `super` helps them know they can call the parent's `__init__` with this technique also.